# How to see if input contain some value?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I've some form like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="website" />
</form>
```

How I can find if user enter website with `http://` or without? I want to show it in:

```
<a href="value from input">
```

Any suggestions how to validate this form and send it to database as right link like: http://website...?

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Because you want to work with database I would say take a look at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words  . Than use `php echo` to echo what you want in your `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use javascript to validate input.

```js
function validate()
{
  var input = document.getElementsByName("website")[0].value;
  if(input.startsWith("http://")) {
      alert("valid input");
      return true;
  }
 
  alert("invalid input");
  return false;
    
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" name="website" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```